# Arduino sketches not working

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I've got an Arduino r3 and a Arduino GPS-shield 2.
The example-sketches and the code on arduino.cc doesn't work.
None of the tips I've read about, both here on SO and everywhere else, doesn't work for me.
I've tried the AT command tester to see if it can handle AT commands, and just get "Invalid or no response from the device". (I've set the right port and baud rate (tested 19200 and 9600)) 
I've even bought new parts to eliminate faulty boards...

For example:

```
// libraries
#include <GSM.h>

// modem verification object
GSMModem modem;

// IMEI variable
String IMEI = "";

void setup()
{
  // initialize serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }

  // start modem test (reset and check response)
  Serial.print("Starting modem test...");
  if (modem.begin())
    Serial.println("modem.begin() succeeded");
  else
    Serial.println("ERROR, no modem answer.");
}

void loop()
{
  // get modem IMEI
  Serial.print("Checking IMEI...");
  IMEI = modem.getIMEI();

  // check IMEI response
  if (IMEI != NULL)
  {
    // show IMEI in serial monitor
    Serial.println("Modem's IMEI: " + IMEI);
    // reset modem to check booting:
    Serial.print("Resetting modem...");
    modem.begin();
    // get and check IMEI one more time
    if (modem.getIMEI() != NULL)
    {
      Serial.println("Modem is functoning properly");
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.println("Error: getIMEI() failed after modem.begin()");
    }
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Error: Could not get IMEI");
  }
  // do nothing:
  while (true);
}
```

Serial monitor says:

```
Starting modemtest... ERROR, no modem answer.
Checking IMEI...Modem's IMEI: 0
Resetting modem...Modem is functioning properly.
```

I've followed every lead I have found (for almost a week) on a whole bunch of forums, but it's still not working. What have I missed?

Comment: I'd examine, why the library returns false on modem.begin() and search for more basic sample code. 

Seems hardware does not fit to the library ?

Comment: It's the brand Arduino on both the motherboard and the shield.

Comment: ...and it's a GSM shield (not GPS)   ;)

Comment: IMEI = 0 and "no modem answer" does not sound too good.<br>
"Modem is functoning properly" just comes from a mistake in your code.